# I would like to know why the tangent method, so used in chemistry, works.

Tags: numerical-methods, analytic-geometry, mathematical-physics, chemistry

[image: Equivalence Point graph]

I would like to know why the tangent method, so used in chemistry, works. Indeed, the teachers seem to take this method for granted but not a single one has been able to justify it to me.  So I leave it to you, sincerely hoping that you will help me.

I know that the equivalence point is the inflection point of the graph, but I can't see why this geometric method works. So I want to know using analysis why this works. Like, if I take the second derivative of it, or something like that but I didn't get anything, I couldn't arrive at a result.

Here are the details of the tangent method:

1. Draw a tangent line on the upper half of the curve, and a tangent line parallel to the previous tangent line in the lower part of the curve.
2. Then take the half distance between the two tangents.
3. Then draw the third tangent parallel to both passing by the midpoint of the distance.

[image: reconstruction of the method]

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a representative expression for the function.  But this seems to be a "logistic-like" S-curve, for which the inflection point is vertically halfway between the parts of the curve which asymptotically approach constant slopes.

Comment: Can you give us more details on this method? We know maths, but we aren't all chemists. ;) What's the purpose of the horizontal-ish tangents? Is the EP (equivalence point) halfway along the vertical-ish tangent)? Or is the EP the point where that tangent crosses the curve?

Comment: An inflection point, by definition, is where the gradient of the tangent line changes from increasing to decreasing, or vice versa, as you move from left to right along the x-axis. Another way of saying it is that it is where the curvature changes sign.

Comment: PM2ring : you draw a tangent line on the upper half of the curve, and a tangent line parallel to the previous tangent line in the lower part of the colurve, then you take the half distance between the 2 tangents then you draw the third tangent parallel to both passing by the midpoint of the distance

Comment: Ok. That info belongs in the question, not buried down here in the comments, so I've edited it into the question for you. But the last step doesn't make sense: the vertical-ish tangent can't be parallel to the horizontal-ish tangents.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is not guaranteed in general. It's likely a good enough approximation for most purposes though. You can concoct examples where this wouldn't give you the right answer. But for $S$ shaped curves, this should work well enough.

Comment: Cameron Williams : But why it works?

Comment: PM2ring : i added another photo to have a more insight about what i'm taking about and in this photo there is the 3rd tangent which i talked about in the last step

Comment: Most mathematical functions don't have this shape at all. Among functions that have two parallel almost-linear segments, the inflection point could be anywhere between the two parallel lines. But titration curves are not arbitrary mathematical functions. The reason to expect an inflection point halfway between the parallel lines could be theoretical or empirical, but in either case it would be based on knowledge of chemistry.

Comment: It seems to be based on an assumption that the curve in some vicinity of the inflection point $x_0$ is an odd function: $f(x)-f(x_0)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c^k(x-x_0)^{2k+1}$.